# How do I do to make my bot say something?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

so my code is like that and i wanted to do something that says "pong" when we say "ping". I don't understand why it doesn't work and I'm a begginner, ty !

```
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
      msg.reply('pong');
    }
  });

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: console log "msg" here

Comment: i don't understand what you're telling me to do :(

Comment: add a console.log(msg); and paste the result here

Comment: In cmd it says :

Comment: "msg" then Logged in as...

Comment: did you add it like this? client.on('message', msg => {
   console.log(msg) ;   if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('pong');
    }
  });

Comment: yes, it's the same as the code i've shown

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages` to your intents

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages
    ]
})

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'ping') {
      msg.reply('pong');
    }
  });

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

[Also you need to enable message content intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jd6nG.png)
But I recommend you to switch to slash commands